# Problem on visualization of a quotient topology

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $ \cong$ is equivalence relation on $S^1 \times [0,1] $ such that

$$ (x,t) \cong (y,s) \iff xt = ys $$

I want to show that $(S^1 \times [0,1]) / \cong $ is homeomorphic to $D^2 = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^2 : ||x || < 1 \} $ with induced topology.

Well, I am having hard time trying to visualize the given space. Can someone help me through this problem? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: For each $t\in(0,1]$, the set $S^1\times\{t\}$ corresponds to the circle of radius $t$ in $D^2$, while $S^1\times\{0\}$ corresponds to the centre of the disk.

Start with the cylinder $S^1\times[0,1]$. Start shrinking the lower edge, $S^1\times\{0\}$, to get a shape like an inverted lampshade:

[image]

Keep shrinking it in and pulling it up until you have an annulus, and then shrink the inner edge of the annulus down to a point; you now have a disk with what used to be $S^1\times\{0\}$ collapsed to the centre point.

Comment: Thanks Brian for your answer, but I would like to ask how can I explicitly give an homeomorphism?

Comment: @DonAnselmo: It almost writes itself if you follow the suggestion in the first paragraph and use polar coordinates for the disk. (I’m assuming that you’re identifying points of $S^1$ by an angle.)

Answer (score 1):

I gauss what you symbolize your $S^1$ as $e^{i\theta}$. Then on $S^1\times[0,1]$, (x,t)=(y,s) let $x=e^{i\theta_1}$, $y=e^{i\theta_2}$ then xt=ys means that

If t=0, xt=ys means s=0 and that every point in $S^1\times 0$ is equivalent.

If t and s are both not equals to zero. Then xt=ys means x=y and t=s.

So this is $D^2$.